# Applying CSS for the drop down naviagtion in SharePoint modern Site - Need help with CSS Classess

Tags: sharepoint-online, css

I created an SPFX application customizer and injected the CSS into our site. I was able to apply customizations to my site. The trouble I am having is to apply the css for the drop down navigation highlighted in yellow.

How to see the classes as that navigation appears only on hover? Any help with applying CSS for the drop down navigation is much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to force the hover state. In Chrome, for example, you can do this by right-clicking on the HTML for the navigation item in the "Elements" tab, then select ":hover" from the "Force state" option. This will allow you to see the CSS classes and styles applied during hover.

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/css/